# Click button in webpage with Javascript

Tags: javascript, android

Currently, I'm doing an application and I need login to this one particular website. Basically, I need to make this button click using a javascript but I have no idea how to.

This is the button code I retrieved from the website:

```
<button type="submit" class="uk-width-1-1 uk-button uk-button-primary uk-button-large">Sign in</button>
```

Thank you for your help in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can click on the button programmatically, in case of pure javascript :

```
(function(){document.querySelector('button[type="submit"]').click();})()
```

In case of Android JS Interface :

```
webView.loadUrl("javascript:(function(){"+
    "l=document.querySelector('button[type=\"submit\"]');"+
    "e=document.createEvent('HTMLEvents');"+
    "e.initEvent('click',true,true);"+
    "l.dispatchEvent(e);"+
    "})()");
```

Comment: Is there other way to not use TagName ? Because that button is not the only button in the page.

Comment: The problem is the button do not have any id, you need to check for something unique to get the correct button (like id, unique class, etc...)

Comment: You can maybe get it with a querySelector :
`document.querySelector('button[type='submit']')`

Answer (score 0):

The general way to have button click events is to use something like jQuery.  For example lets set the button to have an ID

```
<button id="my-button" type="submit" class="uk-width-1-1 uk-button uk-button primary uk-button-large">Sign in</button>
```

Then we would apply a click event to it with jQuery

```
$('#my-button').click(function(){alert('button has been clicked');})
```

Instead of the alert you could put whatever code you want in there :D

Example: [Codepen example](http://codepen.io/KAPastor/pen/oYmjpL)

EDIT:  Example for a class:
[Example for a class](http://codepen.io/KAPastor/pen/gLqaKX)
 (Note that we use a "." instead of "#" in the call)

-Kyle

Comment: The problem is, that's code I retrieved from the website itself. It didn't specify any ID. Just class.

Comment: Ahh that should be ok.  You can just specify the class of the object.  See the edited example above.  But be careful because if there are a bunch of objects with the same class, the click event will execute for all of them.